# Anghami / Sonos self-test suite fail for SSL validation

Tags: sonos

We are using the self test suite provided by **sonos** (latest version from website) in order to test our service implementation. The test fails when checkiong if our server support SSL and TLS 1.0.

> Failed    ssl_validation test_support_tls_10   Instance Messages:  Fail:
>   The partner must support at least one of the following cipher
>   suites:AES128, AES256, RC4-MD5 and RC4-SHA.The server does not support
>   TLS1.0 (expression is False)
>
> Stopped   ssl_validation test_support_secure_renegotiation     Instance
>   Messages:  Stop: One sessionRegegotiation element should be returned,
>   indicating that api.anghami.com supports secure session renegotiation
>   (expression is False)
>
> Failed    ssl_validation test_certificate_expiration   Instance Messages: 
>   Fail: A notBefore and notAfter element should be returned, indicating
>   that api.anghami.com has a date range for validity.
>
> Stopped   ssl_validation test_DNS_has_valid_x509_certificate   Instance
>   Messages:  Stop: A X.509_certificate element should be returned,
>   indicating that api.anghami.com has a valid X.509 certificate for the
>   DNS name (expression is False)

Please note that we have checked our server using:
[the online certificate checking tool provided by Symantec](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp) and the results show that the certificate is valid and installed correctly and that our server clearly supports: TLS 1.2 | TLS 1.1 | TLS 1.0, along with 2 of the required ciphers (please check error message above).

In addition, test results with some screenshots and additional log files were posted on [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/).

Waiting for your feedback.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above your certificate is not set up for secure renegotiation and does not have a valid date range; these are both required in order for us to accept the certificate.  We will follow up on basecamp.